# using jquery droppable and defining what jquery is doing

Tags: jquery, droppable

I am using jqueryui droppable and I am having trouble getting the end result.

jquery:

```
 $( "ol" ).droppable({
  activeClass: "ui-state-default",
  hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "<li></li>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );

  }
```

What does this line do?

```
 $( "<li></li>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
```

is correct to say "Take the text that is in the given "li" and append it to the object "this"?

my problem is that if i loop through the ol and get the id of all the li's in the ol, i get undefined.

```
 $('#butSub').click (function()
 {
            var data = "";
            $('ol').each(function()
            {

                    var olId = $(this).attr('id');
                    $('#'+olId+' li ' ).each(function()
                    {
                            alert($('#'+olId+' li').attr('id'));
                    })
            })
```

Comment: The line creates a new `li`, sets the text to the text of the draggable item that was dropped, then appends it to the `ol`. Your `li` elements aren't given `id`s, so that's why they are undefined in your bottom snippet. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @JasonP, my butSub click event will send data via ajax to a processing page.  In the end i need to send data that has each ol and all the li's appended to it.

Comment: how do i  "Your li elements aren't given ids"   give my li's ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary question, what does this line do

```
$( "<li></li>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
```

Can be broken down as follows

```
$( "<li></li>" ) // create an new, empty li element
    .text( ui.draggable.text() ) // set the text of the new li to the text of the dragged item
    .appendTo(this); // append the new li to "this"
```

In this case, `this` refers to the `ol` that you're attaching the droppable behaviour to

The next bit of your code

```
$('ol').each(function()
{
    var olId = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#'+olId+' li ' ).each(function()
    {
        alert($('#'+olId+' li').attr('id'));
    })
})
```

Has a few things I wanted to point out. First off, you dont need to get the id of the `ol` and use that id to find child `li`, you can just scope to the correct element, so change this:

```
var olId = $(this).attr('id');
$('#'+olId+' li ' ).each(function()
{ ... }
```

to

```
$('li', this).each(function() 
{ ... }
```

In the above, `this` is the `ol`, so `$('li',this)` finds all `li` within the `ol`.

Lastly,

```
alert($('#'+olId+' li').attr('id'));
```

should be

```
alert($(this).text());
```

Now, `this` is the `li` you're looping over (yes, javascript scoping and the `this` keyword can get confusing). Also, as you never gave the newly generated `li` an id, there wont be any, so I changed it to read the `.text()`. If you intended to give your dynamic `li` elements an id, you can change the original line to:

```
$( "<li></li>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).attr('id','someId').appendTo( this );
```

Comment: thanks.  you said "set the text of the li"  where can i append the id to the ol?